# AC_TRY_LINK: Could not link "libssh2"

Tags: c++, c, configure, autotools, libssh2

I am a beginner in `Autotools`. And I have written some working `configure` scripts to invoke `Makefile`s. So, I wanted to make my `configure` script more robust by adding some pre-compilation checks.

For example, I have tried to check whether `configure` script is able to link `pthread` or not.

```
AC_TRY_LINK([#include <pthread.h>],[pthread_attr_t *attr=NULL; pthread_attr_init(attr);],[AC_MSG_RESULT(yes)],[AC_MSG_RESULT(no)])
```

The output is: `yes`

Later, I tried to link `libssh2` in the same way shown above.

```
AC_TRY_LINK([#include <libssh2.h>],[LIBSSH2_SESSION *session;session = libssh2_session_init();],[AC_MSG_RESULT(libssh2_session_init() worked)],[AC_MSG_RESULT(libssh2_session_init did not work)])
```

But the output of this macro shows: `libssh2_session_init did not work`.

I have tried to run a sample code based on `libssh2` and it works. Please look below:

**libsshex.c**

```
#include <libssh2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        LIBSSH2_SESSION *session;
        session = libssh2_session_init();

        if(session)
                printf("session initiated\n");
        else
                printf("session failed\n");
        return 0;
}
```

**COMPILE AND RUN:**

```
root@rohit-Precision-T1500:/test# gcc libsshex.c -lssh2
root@rohit-Precision-T1500:/test# ./a.out 
session initiated
root@rohit-Precision-T1500:/test#
```

As you can see above that linking is successful.

So, why `AC_TRY_LINK` does not link in the case of `libssh2`? Please help me to resolve this one.

Answer (score 0):

You probably really want [AC_CHECK_LIB](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Libraries.html) instead of `AC_TRY_LINK`:

```
AC_CHECK_LIB ([ssh2], [libssh2_session_init_ex],
              [AC_MSG_RESULT(libssh2_session_init linked)], 
              [AC_MSG_RESULT(libssh2_session_init did not link)])
```

The difference is that `AC_CHECK_LIBS` will add `-lssh2` to `LIBS` before the compile and link is attempted.  `AC_TRY_LINK` doesn't do that, it just does the compile and link step, using whatever happens to be in `LIBS`, which in this case is probably nothing.

BTW, you may want to at least examine the [AX_PTHREAD](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_pthread.html) macro for POSIX threads.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It gives me some knowledge. But the above MACRO is not working in my configure script. It gives output as `libssh2_session_init did not link`. I don't understand why. The same implementation works for pthread: `AC_CHECK_LIB(pthread, pthread_attr_init, PTHREAD_LIBS="-lpthread")`. Can u please run and verify from your end? Does that work?

Comment: Have you examined `config.log`?  autoconf puts the output from tests there to help figure out what's going on.

Comment: I found an error in `config.log` :
`/tmp/cc9u1oDP.o: In function `main':
/home/rohit/workspace_2/subsfind/conftest.cpp:32: undefined reference to `libssh2_session_init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`.
Any further clue?

Comment: I got the reason for the failure. Actually, `libssh2_session_init()` is not a function, but a `#define` macro to a function `libssh2_session_init_ex()` in the header `libssh2.h`. Thus I used `libssh2_session_init_ex()` instead of `libssh2_session_init()` in `AC_CHECK_LIB` and this time this worked. I'll update your answer to make it complete. Thanks :)

Comment: The function used by `AC_CHECK_LIB` really needs to be a function, because the sample program output used to test linkage is something very near to `int main { _function_(); return 0; }`.   IIRC, there are no additional includes, etc., because this pretty much what it needs check linkage.

Comment: I guessed this needs to be function the last day. Thanks again. Please update your answer and make `libssh2_session_init` to `libssh2_session_init_ex` so that I can accept your answer because the former is still a macro definition. :)